# When Is Navigation Root Behavior Useful?

Tags: plone, dexterity

After creating a Dexterity type through the web, I try enabling the **Navigation root** behavior. I find this behavior forcing the items displaying as they are in the navigation-root context.

What example use cases will we find this behavior good for?

Environment: Plone 4.3.1

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's useful for when you have any folder that should be the "root" of navigation, such as language folders, or if you have your site split up into independent sub-sections or microsites.

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully there are some real life examples existing already, that is definitely inspiring.

Answer (score 3):

we use it for one thing: microsites.

take a look at [collective.behavior.localregistry](https://github.com/collective/collective.behavior.localregistry) and [collective.behavior.localdiazo](https://github.com/collective/collective.behavior.localdiazo) for a couple of packages using this feature.